# Javascript HTML5 video event canplay not firing on Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, html5-video

I have a HTML page including Javascript which is intended to allow a video (actually just audio content in this case) to play using HTTP Live Streaming on any browser.  In most cases it uses `hls.js` but, in the case of Apple products, I need to do things differently as Safari has native HLS support.

The full page is reproduced below but the important lines are these:

```
else if (video.canPlayType('application/vnd.apple.mpegurl')) {
    video.src = 'music.m3u8';
    video.addEventListener('canplay', startPlaying);
    //document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', startPlaying);
}
```

What should happen is that when the `canplay` event fires the `startPlaying()` function is called and this makes visible a button that the user can press to begin playing the video.  However, on my friend's iPhone 8plus (iOS 11.3.1), this doesn't work: no button is ever visible.  If, instead, I comment out the `video.addEventListener()` line and replace it with the `document.addEventListener()` line then it all works fine: the button is made visible and he can play the stream.

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?  Could be a rookey mistake as I'm not very experienced with this web/script stuff, gives me nose bleeds...  I could, of course, leave it with the DOM load approach but it's not *right* and I'd rather be right.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//Netscape Comm. Corp.//DTD HTML//EN">
<html>
<script src="hls.js/dist/hls.js"></script>

<head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"></head>
<body>
<video id="video"></video>
<button id="play" hidden>Loading</button>
<script>
'use strict';
var video = document.getElementById('video');
var playButton = document.getElementById('play');

function startPlaying() {
    // For mobile browsers the start of playing has to
    // be performed by a user action otherwise it will
    // be ignored
    playButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        video.play();
        video.muted = false;
        video.volume = 1;
        playButton.innerHTML = "Playing";
    });
    playButton.hidden = false;
    playButton.innerHTML = "Ready to play";
}

if (Hls.isSupported()) {
    var hls = new Hls();
    hls.loadSource('music.m3u8');
    hls.attachMedia(video);
    hls.on(Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED, startPlaying);
}
// hls.js is not supported on platforms that do not have Media Source Extensions (MSE) enabled.
// When the browser has built-in HLS support (check using `canPlayType`), we can provide an HLS manifest (i.e. .m3u8 URL) directly to the video element through the `src` property.
// This is using the built-in support of the plain video element, without using hls.js.
else if (video.canPlayType('application/vnd.apple.mpegurl')) {
    video.src = 'music.m3u8';
    video.addEventListener('canplay', startPlaying);
    //document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', startPlaying);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [html5 audio - canplay event doesn't fire on Safari (Mac Desktop)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920297/html5-audio-canplay-event-doesnt-fire-on-safari-mac-desktop)

Comment: Urk.  Well spotted.  Reading [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/326532/safari-now-disables-auto-playing-videos.-heres-how-to-allow-them-for-certain-sites/) suggests that it's not possible to programmatically use the `canplay` event reliably in Safari, as it requires a user to go into a menu and say that your site can autoplay.  You can see why I get nose bleeds up here: how the devil is a normal human being supposed to know how each browser has decided to behave this month!?  I must be getting old...

Comment: From the investigations in the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920297/html5-audio-canplay-event-doesnt-fire-on-safari-mac-desktop), the workaround is to wait on the event `loadedmetadata`, so in my case `video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', startPlaying)`, as this is the last event you're going to get from the HTML5 video element on Safari unless you're in the user-controlled white list.  Confirmed that this works on iOS 11.3.1.

Comment: You're not going crazy or getting old @Rob safari is just a piece of hot trash.

Answer (score 22):

From the investigations in the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920297/html5-audio-canplay-event-doesnt-fire-on-safari-mac-desktop), the workaround is to wait on the event `loadedmetadata`, so in my case `video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', startPlaying)`, as this is the last event you're going to get from the HTML5 video element on Safari unless you're in the user-controlled white list. Confirmed that this works on iOS 11.3.1.